# Office Online Server with 2 certificats

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, office, office-online-server

I have 2 URL of the same web application (extended)

**Intranet** : intranet.domain.com

**Extranet** : extranet.externalurl.com

When i setup **Office Online Server** i use the internal and external parametre but i have an issue with the certificat because i have 2 differents certificat (one for inernal url and one for external url), is there a way i can do an extended OWA ? or put 2 certificat ?

thx

Answer (score 1):

A single certificate needs to have both FQDNs as SANs.

Instead of doing that, I'd recommend only using `-ExternalUrl` and just create an internal DNS record for 'extranet' that points at the OOS server or load balancer IP. SharePoint can only bind to one of them, anyways.